# How to get the selected email from android contacts to the app?

Tags: android, email, android-contacts

I would like to select build an app which comprises of having selecting email id from native contacts.How can I get the selected email value inside the app.How can I achieve this any standalone example on this will be useful.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement the Contact list as below:

   ```
      public class contDetail extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {    
   private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {            
   ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,            
   ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,            
   ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,            
   ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY  
   };
   private int mIdColumnIndex;
   private int mHasPhoneColumnIndex;
   private TextView mPhone;
   @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.pickcontact);
      mPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test); 
   ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1); 
   Cursor c = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
           PROJECTION, null, null, null);       
           mIdColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);      
           mHasPhoneColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c, 
                   new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER },
                   new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }); 
           myList.setAdapter(adapter); 
           myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
           //setOnItemSelectedListener(this);      

      }

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   if (position >= 0) { 
   final Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
   if (c.getInt(mHasPhoneColumnIndex) > 0) { 
   final long contactId = c.getLong(mIdColumnIndex);   
   final Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(  
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
   new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, 
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, 
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC"); 
   try {             
   phones.moveToFirst();   
       mPhone.setText(phones.getString(0));
       String ph = phones.getString(0);
       Intent intent = this.getIntent(); 
       intent.putExtra("SOMETHING",ph ); 
       this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); 
       finish(); 

   } finally {                 
   phones.close();    
   }          
   } else {  
   mPhone.setText(R.string.button_info_text);  
   }}  
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
   mPhone.setText(R.string.button_info_text);
   }

    }
   ```
2. Copy the selected contact in your activity's EditText Box as below:

   ```
         @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)                  {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1)       
      ed1.setText(data.getStringExtra("SOMETHING"));
     if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==2)       
        ed2.setText(data.getStringExtra("SOMETHING"));   
      }
   ```